# How to enable stack trace through included gems and engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rubygems, stack-trace, rails-engines

Yesterday I had a masked error, that should have been very easy to debug with a proper stack-trace. Basically I had a gem which was included in my project which was missing a dependency. The stack-trace failed in my rails application and the actual failure was much deeper in the gems code.

**How can I enable a full trace, through my rails application and into the included gem or engines code?**

Comment: Were you looking at the stack trace in the server log, console, or error page in the browser? Stacktraces are always complete, but rails hides it in the error page.

Comment: This was rspec, and it was not at all complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Rspec you can run the test with the --backtrace or -b option to see the full backtrace. http://www.christophseydel.pro/blog/2013/08/28/enable-full-backtrace-with-rspec/